# How to add a gem dependency and bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

Is it possible to add a gem dependency to a Rails 3 app programmatically through ruby code?

EDIT

I'm trying to achieve that when I launch a rake task or a ruby script my rails app becomes a sass rails app.

I have a bunch of file that needs to be copied and after that I'd like to add:

```
gem 'sass'
```

to my Gemfile and run bundle install automatically.

Comment: Might help if you describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you wanting to add the gem at runtime based on some criteria? Or are you wanting to add the gem dependency based on environment during deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today's railscasts features Guard!

One of the guard extensions is guard-bundler which has this code that can achieve what I need.

https://github.com/guard/guard-bundler/blob/master/lib/guard/bundler.rb

I thought that there was a way to perform similar tasks with the `Bundler` class.